# Join two tables Mysql Java and sent that to jsp as list

Tags: java, mysql, list, jsp

I have two table book and type. One type could be assigned to many books.

This is Book class.

```
    public class Book {
    private int idbook;
    private String name;
    private int type_idtype;



    public int getIdbook() {
        return idbook;
    }

    public void setIdbook(int idbook) {
        this.idbook = idbook;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getType_idtype() {
        return type_idtype;
    }

    public void setType_idtype(int type_idtype) {
        this.type_idtype = type_idtype;
    }
}
```

Another class for Type:

```
    public class Type {
    private int idtype;
    private String typename;

    public int getIdtype() {
        return idtype;
    }

    public void setIdtype(int idtype) {
        this.idtype = idtype;
    }

    public String getTypename() {
        return typename;
    }

    public void setTypename(String typename) {
        this.typename = typename;
    }

    }
```

Another class for query - select with join. I have problem with List and sending list to jsp.

```
        Statement stmt;
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        String sql =  "SELECT book.name, type.typename from book Join type 
       on type.idtype=book.type_idtype";



        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        Book b;
        Type t;
        List<Book> list = new ArrayList<Book>();


        while(rs.next())
        {
            int count = rs.getRow();
            b= new Book();
            t=new Type();
            b.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            t.setTypename(rs.getString("typename"));
            list.add(b);

        }

        request.getSession().setAttribute("list", list);

        response.sendRedirect("booksjsp.jsp");
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
```

List should be send to jsp.

```
   <% List list = (List)session.getAttribute("list"); %>

    <table border="1">

        <tr>

            <th>Name</th>
           <th>Name</th>


        </tr>
        <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
        <c:forEach items="${list}" var="element">
            <tr> 
                <td>${element.name}</td>
                <td>${element.typename}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>

    </table>
```

I can do select and sent it to jsp with one table.  I have problem how to sent to list variables from two classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the @OneToMany relations.
You should add `List<Book> field` for `Type` class, and `Type` field to `Book` class.
Then after selecting, you should retrieve each book, and set for this its type, and opposite, set list of books to type. In this way it works.

In your code, you didn't set any t to book.

```
        int count = rs.getRow();
        b = new Book();
        t = new Type();
        b.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        t.setTypename(rs.getString("typename"));
        list.add(b);
```

It should be something like this

```
        int count = rs.getRow();
        b = new Book();
        t = new Type();
        b.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        t.setTypename(rs.getString("typename"));
        b.setType(t);
        list.add(b);
```

And then `<td>${element.type.typename}</td>`

Please, make sure that you've added field `Type type`), as I told above, please don't only copy code!

Comment: You are welcome, please set my asnwer as finally answer) Good luck